# Adding Multiple Include Functions in PHP

Tags: php, html, php-7

I have a php file which has mostly html codes (index.php). I want to include more than one php classes in it (AirportBAL, PlaneBAL) which have only php code. If I include only one class, there is no problem, the program works perfectly. When I try to add the second include function, the program stops working.

index.php

```
<?php include("../BAL/AirportBAL.php");
      include("../BAL/PlaneBAL.php"); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>
<body>
.....(lots of code code)
<?php 
  $model = new AirportBAL();
  echo $model->GetAirportsCount();                               
?>  
<?php 
  $model = new PlaneBAL();
  echo $model->GetPlanesCount();                               
?>
</body> 

</html>
```

How can I add more than one include functions in it?

**UPDATE**

> The problem solved after replacing the "include" functions with "require_once".

Comment: PHP lines should be terminated with a semi-colon `;`

Comment: do `<?php include("../BAL/AirportBAL.php");
      include("../BAL/PlaneBAL.php");?>` or `<?php include("../BAL/AirportBAL.php") ?>
     <?php include("../BAL/PlaneBAL.php") ?>`

Comment: I fixed it but there is no change.

Comment: So, what do your error-logs say? SHOULD these two files work together? There might be something messing up if the classes aren't meant to work together, for instance. Check the logs.

Answer (score 0):

If you PHP classes don't have any errors it should run. IF all are good then you can use **spl_autoload_register()** function.

spl_autoload_register() allows you to register multiple functions (or static methods from your own Autoload class) that PHP will put into a stack/queue and call sequentially when a "new Class" is declared.

So for example:

```
spl_autoload_register('myAutoloader');

function myAutoloader($className)
{
$path = '/path/to/class';

include $path.$className.'.php';
}

//-------------------------------------

$myClass = new MyClass();
```

Comment: My other classes are working well alone, but after including them to the index.php, the program stops working.